# Why is counting properties slow in Jena TDB?

Tags: sparql, jena

I have different datasets of approx. 120k resources each with about 10-15 properties in a Jena TDB. I'd like to run some statistics and check how properties are distributes across the individual sets.

```
select ?property (count(?y) as ?count) where 
{?x ?property ?y} 
GROUP BY ?property
```

I tried running this simple query that should produce a count for each triple with property *?property* involved.

The query takes ages (5+ Minutes) to finish. Is there a nicer way (besides counting ***manually*** in a forEach loop) or any way to fine-tune ARQ/TDB do improve performance?

Comment: Have you looked at the TDB optimizer documentation http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/optimizer.html

Comment: How are you running the query? What environment are you running in?